# I'm looking for Intel64.iso

Tags: 64-bit, intel, amd-processor

I always confusing when download Ubuntu flavour. My system is 64bit Intel processor(4GB RAM).

when I download 64bit it's downloadind amd64.iso. Upto my knowledge ADM and Intel processors are different. Let me clear this.

How amd64 drivers are compatible with x86_64 architecture?

Comment: @dobey not possible. complete duplicate :p :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"amd64" and "x86-64" are synonymous.

The name "amd64" exists because the 64-bit instruction set used in both AMD and Intel CPUs today is one that was originally invented by AMD.

Usually known as "x86-64", it is also known sometimes as "amd64" honoring its AMD heritage, even though it is used universally by both AMD and Intel.

Both AMD and Intel originally invented their own 64-bit instruction sets.  Intel's was called IA-64 (brand name "Itanium") and it failed to be successful in the consumer market.  The instruction set used by both chipmakers is now the one invented by AMD.  One reason AMD's version was successful was that it was backwards-compatible with 32-bit x86 software.

Software vendors usually refer to it as "x86-64" now which is a less confusing term and is actually quite descriptive, because it is a 64-bit extension of the "x86" instruction set.  However, the term "amd64" continues to be used by various Linux distributions like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The correct 64-bit version is indeed called amd64. That is because AMD was the first to create a 64 bit CPU, so the "tag" stuck, like the i386 for 32-bit, because IBM (i think it was), created the first 32-bit CPU.

So yes, if you have a 64-bit hardware system, you need to download the amd64.iso to make it work.

Comment: sorry Dan Johansen. Its already duplicate question and answered. I can't accept ur answr. But I'll give you up vote

Comment: It's not that AMD was the first to create a 64-bit CPU but that the instruction set used in this case is the one invented by AMD.  Intel also invented a 64-bit instruction set (called IA-64) but it was eventually discontinued and both Intel and AMD now use the instruction set invented by AMD, now known as "x86_64" but also known as "amd64" honoring its AMD heritage.  Part of the reason why AMD's instruction set succeeded in the market is that it is backwards-compatible with 32-bit x86 software.